# Genetic Algo - Crossing multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on this problem of GA

I once did a regular 1 dimension array crossing by simply spliting the array in half and making the new genes out of half of each.

But now I'm with a multidimensional array.

How can I do a cross multidimensional arrays?

Ex:

```
array1 = [
    [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]],
    [[5, 6],
     [7, 8]]
]

array2 = [
    [[10, 9],
     [8, 7]],
    [[6, 5],
     [4, 3]]
]


Desired_array1 = [
    [[1, 9],
     [3, 7]],
    [[5, 5],
     [7, 3]]
]

Desired_array2 = [
    [[10, 2],
     [8, 4]],
    [[6, 6],
     [4, 8]]
]
```

Of course in this case the most inner array size is 2 elements, but it can be any size, and the cross point can be at any point, and not limiting the cross point of the other arrays of the other dimesions.

My idea was to make a empty array with the same structure and fill the elements with each 'chromosome'. Avoiding the 'split' at all. But that might make it a lot slower to do the genetic algorithm.

Anothe idea is byflattening the array, doing a normal 1 dimension crossover, than after that converting the flattened array to the original structure.

So, what should I do? I haven't seem multidimensional array being used in GA, am I doing it wrong by having it that way? Should I change the input to a regular 1 dimensional array and do simple crossover?

By the way, the inputs for the GA come from a neural net, the weights are stored in a multidimensional array, so that the first element of the first dimension of the array is the weights of the first layer, and the last element is the weights of the last layer, the second dimension is for each node weights and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do crossover. For what I know there are no definitive results on the convergency rate of one type of crossover w.r.t. to another or also w.r.t. no crossover (sometimes it is not used at all and in these cases evolution is only based on mutations). 
The improvement of the convergency rate of GA due to crossover is matter of studies. However, up to now, guess you cannot be sure your choice is the best possible (you can also try to make a comparison with different types of crossover, but that won't lead to a general result). However, the strength-point of GAs is not speed but the capability to adapt to different problems, so I wouldn't worry too much about performance as long as the result is satisfactory (unless increase of performances is actually your goal) :)

In your case, since your genes represent the weights of a NN, you may apply crossover "layer per layer" (which, at a glance, should be something like running several GA in parallel, one for each layer of your net). No guarantee that this would be better than applying just one big crossover over the whole multidimensional array (even if it looks more reasonable, as you are applying crossover to "comparable" genes…otherwise you may have your algorithm to switch the weights of the last layer with the weights of the first, and I don't see why this should improve the overall performance).

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, do you have link on the part that no crossover was need, just mutation? I thought that crossover was the main point of GAs. 

About crossing weights of the first layer with the weights of the last, that's not supposed to happen, the crossover will cross weight-by-weight. Like a uniform crossover. So weight 11 of the first layer will only be crossed with weight 11 of the first layer of another gene.

But now you got me thinking about crossing layer-by-layer. And get rid of weights, just change layer 1 of the gene 1 with the layer 1 of the gene 2 and vice-versa.

Comment: GAs w/o crossover can be seen as kind of generalized simulated annealing (in SA it's like if you have a single individual, instead of a population, which gets mutated to solve a minimization problem). You may take a look at http://baibook.epfl.ch. It's not really short but you may find different interesting comments on crossover, and many pointer for further researches.

Comment: Crossover is a bit delicate in particular when dealing with NN, due the high degree of symmetry of nets (very different nets may bring to very similar/good results, while combining them will give something in the middle with very low performance). Again, no final word can be said (until now, up to my knowledge). Just try, if it works that's fine! After all, that's also the philosophy of trial&error learning! :)

Answer (score 0):

All ideas are fine, and your representation is OK. You do not need to use 1D array as a representation, if 2D works better for you. Which crossover operator is the most suitable one really depends on what your matrix represents. In general, nobody can tell what is more appropriate, it is very problem-dependent.

For instance, you can do a crossover based on a line that cuts the matrix in two parts in any angle and position... 
You would generate random parameters dx, dy (double) of a vector going from 0,0, and possibly also shift it along the edges of the rectangle (top or left). The line will divide your matrix into two parts - alleles from one part go from the first parent, alleles from the other part will go from the other parent.

To simplify this, you could work only with the lines that are parallel to the rectangle borders. Or you could create your own operators, or ways how to implement this as you want, it all depends on what parts of the genotype make sense to keep together.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to add anything to the answers already present, but for some weird coincidence, i have already developed a program in c# that does what you are trying to do (in my case i don't use multidimensional inputs, but i apply crossover on the multidimensional weight matrices).
The project is open sourced [here](http://github.com/NeuralDip/GNT)

you can download binaries from [here](http://www.diversemechanics.com)

and i have used [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.153.1572&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper for crossOvering.